# Google TextToSpeech synthesizeSpeech throws Exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I've followed the QuickStart guide for Google TextToSpeech API, and it works when I deploy it to the GAE server. However the line of code:

```
SynthesizeSpeechResponse response = textToSpeechClient.synthesizeSpeech(input, voice,audioConfig);
```

throws an exception:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Failed computing credential metadata
```

when I run the program from localhost using

```
mvn appengine:devserver
```

I have set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and I know this is working as NewBuilder call fails when this is not set.
So, why do I get an exception on localhost, but not when deployed on my GAE? And how do I fix it?

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a new empty Service Account for the Text-to-Speech API ?

Does GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS point to the JSON credentials (API Key) file in local?

The fact that you get an authentication error only in local certainly means the key is not accessible by the program at runtime.

Which tutorial are you following?